# Is it possible to have a screen macro for this?

Tags: gnu-screen, macro

Here's my `.screenrc`:

```
defscrollback 5000

vbell on
vbell_msg "   dierre!!!  ----  Wuff!!  "


screen -t GRINDER ssh dierre@grinder.dierre.lan
screen -t TRUNK

attrcolor b ".I"
termcap xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
defbce "on"

# caption always "%3n %t%? @%u%?%? [%h]%?%=%c"
# hardstatus alwaysignore
hardstatus alwayslastline '%{gk}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{wk}%?%-Lw%?%{=b kR}[%{W}%n%f %t%?(%u)%?%{=b kR}]%{= kw}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}]%{=b C}[ %D %m/%d %C%a ]%{W}'
```

This will open two `screen`(s). The next step I have to do is:

1. `Ctrl+A -> S` to split the screen
2. `Ctrl+A -> \t` to go the the empty screen
3. `Ctrl+A -> "` to open the screen list

Now I can choose the other screen and therefore I have a terminal with two splitted screen.

Is there a way to create a macro for this? Really annoying to do it every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add at the end of your `.screenrc` the following lines:

```
split
focus
other
```

To run multiple command, each in a separated split window:

```
screen -t title1 app1
split
focus
screen -t title2 app2
split
focus
screen -t title3 app3
```

and so on.

Comment: can you generalize the answer for n screens?

Comment: @dierre: do you mean: start `n` apps, split the screen, go to the empty screen and choose one of the n running apps?

Comment: I start n apps, I want all n apps in a screen splitted in n